# Add custom GraphQL resolvers and types into Prisma/Nexus schema

Tags: javascript, graphql-js, prisma-graphql, nexus-prisma

Using: *TypeScript*, *Prisma*, *MySQL*,  *GraphQLServer*, *ApolloClient*, building schema this way:

```
const schema = makePrismaSchema({
  // Provide all the GraphQL types we've implemented
  types: [Query, Mutation, User, Post],...
```

And then:

```
  const server = new GraphQLServer({
    schema,
    context: { prisma }
  });
```

How to combine that with custom resolvers and types unrelated to the SQL?

(I would like to call some REST endpoint by the GQL as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `nexus` was created to be used alongside `prisma`, it's really just a schema builder. You could easily use it to create a schema without even utilizing Prisma. For example:

```
export const User = prismaObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  definition(t) {
    t.list.field('comments', {
      type: 'Comment',
      resolve(root, args, ctx) {
        return getComments();
      },
    });
  },
})

export const Comment = prismaObjectType({
  name: 'Comment',
  definition(t) {
    t.string('body');
  },
})
```

Here `getComments` can return an array of comment objects, or a Promise that resolves to one. For example, if you're calling some other API, you'll normally return a Promise with the results of the call. As shown above, the resolver exposes the parent value, the field's arguments and a context object -- you can use any of this information in determining how to resolve a particular field.

Comment: One thing not immediately obvious to some is that you'd need to add it to types when creating the schema:

`
makePrismaSchema({
  types: [OtherTypes..., Comment],
})
`